# CocoaPods Trunk cannot push update: "You need to register a session first."

Tags: cocoapods

I am attempting to publish my library using the new [CocoaPods Trunk](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/) service.

```
pod trunk push your-library.podspec
```

This gives the error:

> [!] You need to register a session first.

How does one register a session?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Register a CocoaPods session in Terminal like so:

`pod trunk register name@example.org 'Your Name' --description='macbook pro'`

You will then be emailed at the provided address, click a link, and confirm your session.

http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk.html

Comment: I have tried that and get the error: [!] Unknown arguments: trunk register .... any suggestions?

Comment: yes, i figured it out.  I had an older version of cocoapods installed... updated it and now it worked.

Comment: @pkamb how much time it will take to push the trunk for the first time ??