# Error when trying to run `pod trunk push [cocoapod].podspec`

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

When trying to push an update to my cocoapod framework to the repo with `pod trunk push` as mentioned in the title, I get the following error:

> [!] Authentication token is invalid or unverified. Either verify it with the email that was sent or register a new session.

I've updated the cocoapod before, how do I verify my email or session?

Edit: Sometimes I also get the error: `[!] You need to register a session first.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CocoaPods Trunk cannot push update: "You need to register a session first."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900688/cocoapods-trunk-cannot-push-update-you-need-to-register-a-session-first)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

1. Run the following command in terminal:

   `pod trunk register yourEmail@example.com 'Your Name'`
2. Click the link in the email that is sent to you.
3. Run your `pod trunk push` command in terminal again

Comment: how much time it will take to push for the first time ??

Comment: @vijeesh I suppose that's a factor of the size of your cocoapod and the speed of your internet service, however for me it was just a few seconds.

Comment: Note: `grep -A2 'trunk.cocoapods.org' ~/.netrc` to view registered login and token.

Answer (score 9):

This failed me just now, looks like there is an additional requirement to perform the registration as [outlined here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk.html).

1. From terminal run: `pod trunk register myemail@domain.com 'MyName'`
2. Click on the link for the email sent to your address
3. Run `pod trunk push` again

To highlight, the difference from Justin's answer was to include the **name value**. It would not allow me to register without it.